# Optimize Javascript function for memory leaks

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

Due to some reasons i am optimizing javascript functions and at this time i am investigating which i can optimize following code or not.

I have following array:

```
var usageArray = [5,10,20,10,15,18,19,20,21,24,23,28,29,27,10,10];
```

I want to push value to end of this array without changing on count of nodes and create array with following structure:

```
[[0, 5], [1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 10], [4, 15], [5, 18], [6, 19], [7, 20], [8, 21], [9, 24], [10, 23], [11, 29], [12, 27], [13, 10], [14, 10]]
```

I will pass new value each 10 second with following function:

```
function tUsage(value) {
    usageArray = usageArray.slice(1);
    usageArray.push(value);
    var i = [];
    for (var s = 0; s < usageArray.length; ++s) {
        i.push([s, usageArray [s]]);
    }
    console.log([i]);
    //Free Memory
    i = null;
    s = null; 
}
```

Is there any way which i write this function in the better way, because fire this function each 10 seconds and want to remove its memory leaks.

Comment: `[{0,5},{1,10},...]` as an array structure in JavaScript makes no sense. Do you mean `[{0: 5}, {1: 10}, ...]` or `[[0, 5], [1, 10], ...]`?

Comment: It's not necessary to delete the local variables, and it's not allowed at all in "strict" mode.

Comment: @Phylogenesis question edited

Comment: @Pointy question edited

Comment: Now your example seems to have no relationship between your before and after arrays. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @Phylogenesis it has relashion, those was for example. i edited that again

Comment: Okay, as shown, this should reduce down to a simple `usageArray.map(function (value, index) { return [index, value]; });`

Answer (score 1):

As per the discussion above, your entire function can be reduced to a single [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) call:

```js
var usageArray = [5,10,20,10,15,18,19,20,21,24,23,28,29,27,10,10];

var newArray = usageArray.map(function (value, index) { return [index, value]; });
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: how we remove first node and add new value to end of that?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) removes the first item from an `Array`.

Comment: can you please send full function according to my descriptions?